# How Sign in automatic and Remember me works in android application?

Tags: android, database, authentication

I am implementing a Login Screen in an Android application. There are Checkboxes for "Remember me" and "Sign In Automatic"". Please suggest way to implement this functionality?

Comment: You would most likely want to use `SharedPreferences` to save the username and a secured version of the password, so you can read these on startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my suggestion the purpose of rememer me is different.

The flow should be like this.

Initially login with resisterd is and passwrod. 
Store it in a shared preference as mentioned in the above answer
( Shared preference is always recommended thogh the same can be achieve using static variables also. But static variable are not always reliable )

Now whenever the app is launched check the content of sharedpref for this purpose and only if it is not null , user should be prompted to login again

But the purpose of remember me is that when user logout , next time when loggin , it should show the previous used username / password .
When there is a loggin for the app, there should be a logout option.
Logout option shoud take user to the login page.
Here if remeber me was checked previously, his previous user name will come. 
If not checked these fields will be blank.

One more suggestion is that keep login only for user specific portion of the app.
Its not a good user interface if user is forced to login too see what app is .

These are some suggestions

Answer (score 5):

For remember me, Use shared preferences to store it locally (the boolean value - TRUE or FALSE). If the checkbox is checked, then store the username, password in memory using shared preferences again. When you open the app, check if the shared preferences can give values for username and password. If yes, then you can automatically start the login process. Else just show up the login screen. Clear?

Edit -

Use this to store the values in onClickListener of login button

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putString("LOGIN_ID", username_field.getText().toString());
        prefsEditor.putString("LOGIN_PSWD", password_field.getText().toString());
        prefsEditor.putBoolean("REMEMBER", checkbox.isChecked());
        prefsEditor.commit();
```

Again, on the app start up, use this code to read the values and login -

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        boolean isRemember = myPrefs.getBoolean("REMEMBER", false);
   if(!isRemember)
     //Go to login screen. 
else
{     
String id = myPrefs.getString("LOGIN_ID", "");
String pswd = myPrefs.getString("LOGIN_PSWD", "");
//try to autologin now with these values
}
```

Comment: Its fine. will you please post an example? thanks Alot for your Valueable suggestion

Comment: if some one have other suggestion or this type code please post.

Comment: there is error define getsharesPreferece method.what to do with this?

Comment: how to getsharedprefence method

Comment: I am implementing these on On click method .so what should be context.

Comment: can we use shared Preference across the other Activity.

Comment: should i make separate class before Login? and aplication go to that when starts?